# Creatine and protein schedule

Tags: bodybuilding, protein, creatine, football

I'm 17 and I workout 5 times a week with my uncle after school for conditioning for football next year and I need to get stronger and bigger and we lift everyday and run on the treadmill everyday and after my workouts I take one scoop of 6 star whey protein and one scoop of body fortress creatine a day and I drink lots of water so Is it safe for my body?

Comment: I don't think we can say whether or not this is safe for you in particular, but that protein/creatine schedule looks pretty normal to me.

Comment: I am not sure what this question is about. Safety of supplements, daily lifting or drinking lots of water?

Comment: could you possibly edit the question so we may have a better understanding of what you wish to know?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to bulk up, working out 5 days a week is counter-productive.  You need to get your body to [supercompensate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercompensation) and you won't get there without rest.

I'm going to assume you isolate different muscle groups on different days, something like

```
Mon: Chest/Triceps
Tues: Back/Biceps
Wed: Shoulder/Forearms
Thurs:Legs
Fri: Core/Abs
```

because that's what everyone reads in magazines and people tell others to follow programs like this without really knowing why they even follow these schedules...

Now I'm going to pull some Rippetoe/Mehdi stuff on you :)  What you want to be doing (assuming you want to become stronger and bigger for football) is compound lifts.  You want to be squatting 3x a week.  You want to be getting your deadlift and bench numbers up.  Drop any exercise that has the word "curl" in it. Drop leg presses. Drop triceps extensions, lat pull-downs, etc...  Compound lifts baby!

Basically, an ideal schedule would be one day on, one day off, and cardio on the weekend.

Quite honestly, to achieve your goal, you could do it with 5 simple exercises.

```
    Squats  
    Benchpress 
    Barbell Rows  
    Chin-ups 
and most importantly, Deadlifts
```

Basically I'm recommending [5x5 Stronglifts](http://stronglifts.com/stronglifts-5x5-beginner-strength-training-program/).  I followed this for hockey, and in 3 months, with the right diet, I put on 25 pounds, and judging by my BF%, 12-14 of those lbs were pure muscle.

Follow this training regimen, get 200+ grams of protein, 3000+ kCal in you per day, and you'll gain muscle. Start small, increase the weight every workout.  Muscle confusion is a myth. If you want to get stronger keep lifting and build up to more weight, your body will evolve naturally to handle the added strain.  That's how you get stronger.

Answer (score -2):

The recommended age for working out and doing heavy strength exercises is 16. When it comes to your protein shake and creatine, then the amount of protein and creatine isn't dangerous for your body.

The whey protein is optimal for your training, if you want to gain extra muscles. The creatine  is just for your own motivation, cause the only thing creatine does, is that it reduces the aching in your muscles.

Another thing I read in your question was that you lift everyday? There's no point in lifting everyday if you want to gain muscles. You can run the treadmill, in order to get in shape, but  you must notice that it takes 36 hours for the muscle fibres to recover. Which means you would gain muscles faster if you for example lifted weights 4 days a week, and then had 3 days of recovery.

Comment: Well we workout 5 times a week and take weekends off that gives us two days off and and something I didn't add is it best to take a scoop of creatine everyday after my workouts I only take one tho and one scoop of protein

Comment: -1. Whey protein may or may not be optimal depending on the persons own reactions to it and their diet. If they are sufficient in protein, it doesn't really do much. Also, creatine is one of the few supplements that actually works. It provides more energy for short burst, intense activity such as weightlifting by providing phosphates to turn adenosine diphosphate (ADP) back into adenosine triphosphate (ATP) which is the primary source for energy (The breaking of the phosphate bond going from ATP to ADP is what creates the energy). Reading the label instructions should guide on creatine dosage.

Comment: Also does creatine deform muscles because someone at my high school told me that?

Comment: There is no evidence that creatine deforms muscles. It is one of the few supplements that works that has been evaluated and is accepted by sport governing bodies (Including the IOC). If anything, it visually makes the muscles appear "fuller", as it promotes fluid retention in muscle cells. There have been a few side effects/deaths related to creatine, but these have been extreme cases where large amounts were taken during periods of cutting/dehydration that caused kidney and other problems.

Comment: Does working out all week and weekends off do any better that three days off?

Comment: The only 'problem' with creatine is that its effects are not persistent after you stop consuming it, you have to stay 'on' it to receive them.

Comment: Is week days of working out and weekends off a good schedule

Comment: @JohnP It's funny that you guys actually are giving me -1 for this answer, cause it's correct .. It's scientifically proven that creatine only works with some people, others are immune to it. So even if it does work with some people, then many other people wont feel the difference ..

Comment: @Elholm - There is no such thing as a "creatine non responder", there are just people who truly don't understand the effects and how it actually works in the body.